# How to Pass values from one Activity to another Activity by using Tap on List View Item

Tags: android

I am writing an App in which i am trying to **allow user to edit a quantity of an Item already in Cart, by Tap on Item in List View**..

1. I want to show Quantity entered by user in EditText, when do Tap on an Item in Cart
2. How can i show description of an Item, when do Tap on an Item in Cart 
   [like : still i am just getting description word, not getting description of an 
   Item which i am showing in Screen Number:2]

I am using below code in getView() method in CartAdapter.java:

```
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
public static final String KEY_TOTAL = "total";
public static final String KEY_QTY = "qty";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "imageUri";


  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = myinflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_cart_edit, null);
        vi.setClickable(true);
        vi.setFocusable(true);          

        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   

            HashMap<String, String> item = Session.item_data.get(position);
            Intent intent= new Intent(myactivity, com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.class);

            intent.putExtra(KEY_TITLE,  item.get(com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.KEY_TITLE));
            intent.putExtra(KEY_COST, item.get(com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.KEY_COST));
            intent.putExtra(KEY_TOTAL, item.get(com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.KEY_TOTAL));
            intent.putExtra(KEY_QTY, item.get(com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.KEY_QTY));
            intent.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, (com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            intent.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.KEY_THUMB_URL);
            myactivity.startActivity(intent);

        }       
    });
```

Note: To get Description of an Item, i also tried with below code, but not worked, i know here is very small change need to do, but really i don't know what is that change:

```
   intent.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, item.get(com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.KEY_DESCRIPTION));
```

Comment: you are trying to pass data from Fragment to Activity or from Fragment to Fragment?

Comment: Activity to Activity not using Fragment @Android-Developer

Comment: Please simplify your code to the minimal amount needed to illustrate what you are asking about. I suggest that you start a brand new Android project so that you don't have extra code which is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I noticed here that when I saw this question, I saw 4-5 answers of this question here posted and everyone get down voted :D. I don't know everyone deleted their answers. @ChulbulPandey You will never get solution line by line as you want. You should get trick from answer rather than down voting. Otherwise no one get interested to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent= new Intent(myactivity, com.easy.shoppingcart.SingleItem.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

on the other side of activity(SingleItem) inside oncreate()

```
int position;
if(this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
                            position = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("position"));

    }
```

Use this position to get the values.

```
HashMap<String, String> item = Session.item_data.get(position);
```